# What is a samba user?

Tags: samba

I have an owncloud running on my bananapi. In the data dir of owncloud I am linking to some folders on an external HDD.

Moreover I want to use the linked folders, like Music, Videos etc. as a Shared folder in my network, so Plex and Back in Time can access it.

I am using Samba for this. How are access rights maintained?
There is a thing called *Samba User*.. What is this for? My folders are `www-data:www-data:`, as owncloud recommends using these ownerships.

To access them via Samba I do not want to set the `chmod` to `777`.

How do I gain them perms, so I can use a Samba Client to read, write the shared folders?

Comment: "To access them via Samba I do not want to set the chmod to 777. " Just for that you get an upvote from me :+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A samba user is a normal Ubuntu user that you create and then use to set up samba with. Samba has its own password program called "smbpasswd" with ...

```
smbpasswd -a {user}
```

That gives access to /home/{user}/

`/etc/samba/smb.conf` also lets you set a share for that samba user

```
[accounts]
comment = Accounts data directory
path = /directory/dir/
valid users = {user}
public = no
writable = yes
```

That last one makes files writable.

Comment: neat. So I just can add a user to www-data. Or create a unified group.

Comment: @DanielHitzel yes sir. That will work :-) Do change the default directory though. Never a good thing to use a /home/ for things like this.